# p:timeline changed event action delay

Tags: jsf, primefaces, timeline

I set up a PrimeFaces `p:timeline`, after each zoom in or zoom (event : changed) start method that read some database. i have a issue with this operation, users mostly zoom fiew levels in. So they click button for example several times in a row. For example they would like zoom from days to minutes, so they click button 4, 5 times in a row. After every click starts methods that read a database, and this is an issue for me. This causes system delays. Is it possible somehow to wait with event :changed until user stops zooming?

Comment: PrimeFaces has ajax delay, but I'm not sure if you receive the right information in the final event (the real zoom factor)

Comment: It's good to have someone smarter to get advice. Problem solved, thank you.

Comment: Please create an answer yourself if the plain delay was not enough. Otherwise I'll find a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, solution: add a ajax delay to rangechanged event:

```
<p:ajax event="rangechanged" delay="#{schedulerControler.delay}" listener="#{schedulerControler.update}"  />
```

Bean:

```
private long delay = ((long) (100 * 10));
```